# How to add NVIDIA 970 GTX to HP Proliant DL580

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, hp-proliant

I bought an HP Proliant DL580 and I would like to add a graphics card to make GPU calculations.

The card fit perfectly, but I need to plug in the graphics card power cable to a power supply.
Where can I plug in this cable? It looks like an 8-pin cable

Answer (score 0):

The 8-pin connector comes from the power supply. It is either directly connected to the power supply already or you will need a MOLEX to 8-pin or 4+4/6+2 - pin adapter to correctly connect the GPU to the power source.

Comment: Finnally, I order the MOLEX to 8pin and it doesn't fit.cable cost 50$ and is not usable. Plug is too small for the server socket. I needed a PCIe Modular cable

Comment: Hmm... not sure how it could be too small? It should go from MOLEX on the Power Supply into the ports on top of the graphics card. It's a universal size, unless you need more than ONE 8-pin connector.

Comment: Maybe its the one that I bought that was not standard. I receved a second cable and this one fits perfectly. https://www.moddiy.com/products/Antec-HCG-620W-Modular-PSU-Sleeved-PCIe-10%252dPin-to-8%252dPin-%252b-6%252dPin-Cable.html

Comment: Great news! Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but the connects for GFX power are on the PSU controller.

Also, what gen is the server?

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02514211